# Combine two simple SQL queries two one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries and I want to combine them into one query

1st query: this query finds the average for each student in each subject:

```
SELECT  
    StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, ClassName, 
    AVG(Grade) AS 'average for this subject'
FROM tests
INNER JOIN students ON tests.StudentID = students.StudentID
GROUP BY StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, ClassName;
```

2nd query: this query finds the average for each student his total average for whole his final grades:

```
SELECT  
    StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, AVG(average) AS total_average
FROM
    (SELECT   
         StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, AVG(Grade) AS average
     FROM 
         tests
     INNER JOIN 
         students ON tests.StudentID = students.StudentID
     GROUP BY 
         StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, ClassName) AS t
GROUP BY 
    StudentFirstName, StudentLastName;
```

For example: the  grades of me(aka Error404) are:

- **Algebra:** first exam: 99, second exam: 97, third exam: 96 ---> **1st query gives Average:** 97.3333 for this subject
- **Machine-learning:** first exam: 95, second exam: 94 ---> **1st query gives Average:** 94.5 for this subject

2nd query returns total average of AVG(97.3333,94.5)=95.91665 for student named error404

Table 1 - **Students**:

```
      pk-INT           VARCHAR             VARCHAR
    +-----------+------------------+-----------------+
    | StudentID | StudentFirstName | StudentLastName |
    +-----------+------------------+-----------------+
    |         1 | agam             | rafaeli         |
    |         2 | amir             | aizinger        |
    |         3 | avi              | caspi           |
    |         4 | avia             | wolf            |
    +-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Table 2 - **Tests**:

```
 PK-VARCHR    PK-VARCHR     PK&FK-INT   INT
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| TestDate   | ClassName  | StudentID | Grade |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2017-07-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    88 |
| 2017-08-02 | Algo       |         1 |    97 |
| 2017-09-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    80 |
| 2017-09-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    97 |
| 2017-09-01 | Set-theory |         1 |    85 |
| 2017-09-04 | Calcules   |         1 |    86 |
| 2016-05-03 | Set-theory |         2 |    84 |
| 2016-07-02 | Calcules   |         2 |    89 |
| 2016-07-04 | Algo       |         2 |    83 |
| 2016-07-05 | Algebra    |         2 |    79 |
| 2016-06-03 | Algebra    |         3 |    99 |
| 2016-07-02 | Algo       |         3 |    97 |
| 2016-07-03 | Calcules   |         3 |    96 |
| 2016-09-03 | Set-theory |         3 |    95 |
| 2016-06-03 | Algebra    |         4 |    78 |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

Sample data:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS error404;
CREATE DATABASE error404;

USE error404

CREATE TABLE students
(
    StudentID        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    StudentFirstName VARCHAR(25),
    StudentLastName  VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
);

INSERT INTO students (StudentFirstName, StudentLastName) 
VALUES ('agam', 'rafaeli'), ('amir', 'aizinger'), ('avi', 'caspi'),
       ('avia', 'wolf ');

CREATE TABLE tests
(
    testid    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TestDate  DATE,
    ClassName VARCHAR(25),
    StudentID INT NOT NULL,
    Grade     INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (testid),
    KEY (StudentID)
);

INSERT INTO tests (TestDate, ClassName, StudentID, Grade) 
VALUES ('2017-07-01', 'Algebra', 1, 88), 
       ('2017-08-02', 'Algo', 1, 97),
       ('2017-09-01', 'Algebra', 1, 80), 
       ('2017-09-01', 'Algebra', 1, 97),
       ('2017-09-01', 'Set-theory', 1, 85), 
       ('2017-09-04', 'Calculus', 1, 86),
       ('2016-05-03', 'Set-theory', 2, 84), 
       ('2016-07-02', 'Calculus', 2, 89),
       ('2016-07-04', 'Algo', 2, 83), 
       ('2016-07-05', 'Algebra', 2, 79),
       ('2016-06-03', 'Algebra', 3, 99), 
       ('2016-07-02', 'Algo', 3, 97),
       ('2016-07-03', 'Calculus', 3, 96), 
       ('2016-09-03', 'Set-theory', 3, 95),
       ('2016-06-03', 'Algebra', 4, 78);
```

I want this result:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| StFirstName  | StLastName   | ClassName    | aveInSubject | totalAve     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| name1        | lname1       | algebra      |  80          |  87          |
| name1        | lname1       | algo         |  88          |  87          |
| name1        | lname1       | calcul       |  93          |  87          |
| name2        | lname2       | algebra      |  70          |  74.3        |
| name2        | lname2       | algo         |  76          |  74.3        |
| name2        | lname2       | calcul       |  77          |  74.3        |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` the result of per subject average and total average per student.

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.totalAvg
FROM (SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName,AVG(Grade) AS `average for this subject`
      FROM tests
      INNER JOIN students ON tests.StudentID=students.StudentID
      GROUP BY StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName
     ) t1
JOIN (SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,AVG(`average for this subject`) as totalAvg
      FROM (SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName,AVG(Grade) AS `average for this subject`
            FROM tests
            INNER JOIN students ON tests.StudentID=students.StudentID
            GROUP BY StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName
           ) t
      GROUP BY StudentFirstName,StudentLastName
     ) t2 
ON t1.StudentFirstName=t2.StudentFirstName and t1.StudentLastName=t2.StudentLastName
```

EDIT: For future versions of MySQL (starting version 8.0) with window functions, the query could be simplified to

```
select studentfirstname,studentlastname,classname,avgPerSubject
,sum(avgPerSubject) over w/count(*) over w as totalAvg
from (select distinct 
      s.studentfirstname,s.studentlastname,t.classname,
      avg(t.grade) over(partition by s.studentfirstname,s.studentlastname,t.classname) as avgPerSubject
      from tests t
      join students s on s.studentid=t.studentid
     ) t
window w as (partition by studentfirstname,studentlastname)
```

Comment: This gives wrong result for 'totalavg ' column, the total avg should be the average of the averages. i.e I my avg in algebra is 88.33,my avg in algo is 97, my avg in cacules is 86, my avg in algebra is 77.5. so my totalavg should be: (88.33+97+86+77.7)/4 = 87.208 and **not** 86.1429 as this query gives, can you please edit?

Comment: are you trying to get the average per student or average of averages per subject per student?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala average of averages per subject per student

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Thanks a lot !!, can you post *Another*  answer for same query but in another way? is it possible? I promise to vote for another "version" for this query, please!!! this will help me a lot!!!

Comment: @Error404 .. check out the edit which uses window functions.